# How toggle fillColor from a selected polygon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm using `google-maps-react` to plot some polygons in a map.

I would like to show the user what polygon he selected. The problem is when the user select on polygon and click in another polygon, It appears that there are two selected polygons, there are two polygons with a blue background.

Can you tell me how to do the toggle between the polygons? If the user clicks on another polygon, the first polygon returns to its original color.

Here's my code I put in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-color-txixv?file=/src/index.js)

**Render my map:**

```js
<Map
  google={props.google}
  style={{ width: "80%", height: "80%", position: "relative" }}
  zoom={14}
  initialCenter={{ lat: -22.25176048208858, lng: -47.70295694770419 }}
  clickableIcons={false}
  className={"map"}
  center={{ lat: -22.25176048208858, lng: -47.70295694770419 }}
>
  {poligons.map((paths) => (
    <Polygon
      onMouseover={mouseOver}
      onMouseout={mouseOut}
      paths={paths}
      options={polygonOptions}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />
  ))}
</Map>
```

**Handle Click events:**

```js
const handleClick = (props, polygon) => {
  const paths = polygon.getPaths().getArray();
  const coordinates = paths.map((path) => {
    const points = path.getArray();
    return points.map((point) => [point.lng(), point.lat()]);
  });

  polygon.setOptions({
    fillColor: "blue"
  });

  return {
    type: "Polygon",
    coordinates
  };
};
```

Showing an image makes it easier to see the problem happening:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the last selected polygon by keeping it in the state. If there is already is a selected polygon you can set the `fillColor` of that polygon to the default color, `#02482b` for this map.

```
const [currentHighlightedPolygon, setCurrentHighlightedPolygon] = useState(
  null,
);

// ...

const handleClick = (props, polygon) => {
  const paths = polygon.getPaths().getArray();
  const coordinates = paths.map(path => {
    const points = path.getArray();
    return points.map(point => [point.lng(), point.lat()]);
  });

  polygon.setOptions({
    fillColor: 'blue',
  });

  if (currentHighlightedPolygon !== null) {
    currentHighlightedPolygon.setOptions({
      fillColor: '#02482b',
    });
  }

  setCurrentHighlightedPolygon(polygon);

  return {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates,
  };
};

// ...
```

Here's a fork of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-color-forked-u179j?file=/src/Map.js.